# Filter data using multiple where conditions in Eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm using multiple `where` conditions and `orWhere` conditions to filter data. Also, I'm using `whereBetween` to set date range. As filters I'm sending from and to dates, array list of filters. But when I check with more filters I'm getting all data that not in the date range. Here is a filter data sample.

```
'from_date' => date("Y-m-d"),
'to_date' => date("Y-m-d"),
'filters' => ['', "pending","won","cancel"]
```

here is my code

```
$this->model
    ->leftJoin('vehicle_details', 'vehicle_details.id', '=', 'vehicles.vehi_details_id')
    ->leftJoin('makes', 'makes.model_id', '=', 'vehicle_details.model_id')
    ->when(($attbutes->from_date || $attbutes->to_date), function ($q) use ($attbutes) {
        return $q->whereBetween('vehicles.auc_date', [$attbutes->from_date, $attbutes->to_date]);
    })
    ->when(($attbutes->filters && isset($attbutes->filters[0])), function ($q) use ($attbutes) {
        if (strtolower($attbutes->filters[0]) == "pending") {
            return $q->whereNull('vehicles.vehi_details_id');
        } elseif (strtolower($attbutes->filters[0]) == "1" || strtolower($attbutes->filters[0]) == "0") {
            return $q->whereRaw('LOWER(`vehicles`.`won_status`)= ?', intval($attbutes->filters[0]));
        } else {
            return $q->whereRaw('LOWER(`vehicle_details`.`status`)= ?', strtolower($attbutes->filters[0]));
        }
    })
    ->when(($attbutes->filters), function ($q) use ($attbutes) {
        foreach ($attbutes->filters as $index => $filter) {
            if ($index > 0) {
                if (isset($filter[$index]) && strtolower($attbutes->filters[$index]) == "pending") {
                    $q->orWhereNull('vehicles.vehi_details_id');
                } elseif (isset($filter[$index]) && (strtolower($attbutes->filters[$index]) == "1" || strtolower($attbutes->filters[$index]) == "0")) {
                    $q->orWhereRaw('LOWER(`vehicles`.`won_status`)= ?', intval($attbutes->filters[$index]));
                } else {
                    $q->orWhereRaw('LOWER(`vehicle_details`.`status`)= ?', strtolower($attbutes->filters[$index]));
                }
            }
        }

    })
    ->get([
        'vehicles.*',
        'vehicle_details.color as vehi_color',
        'vehicle_details.grade as vehi_grade',
        'makes.model_name',
    ]);
```

Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: In your third filter, you should surround the query in a where closure in order for the `orWhere` clauses to affect the other filters. Check this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#or-statements . As a sidenote, that code block lacks readibility, you should extract those conditions in query scopes (also, making use of Eloquent instead of the Query Builder directly)

Comment: @KennyHorna Thanks for your comment. Can you please explain a bit of this `you should extract those conditions in query scopes` ? Thanks again

Comment: sure, you can read more here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: @KennyHorna Thanks

Comment: @KennyHorna I have tried it with adding it inside `orWhere` closure, but I got the same result.